# Is there a way to delete (trim) some jumplist items?

Tags: jumplist

I want a jumplist like tree (undotree), or like taglist stack (trim some needless items), but I can not find any way to delete jumplist items.
I think about hook jump action for my own jumplist, but I can not find some efficient way (CursorMove?).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I write a experiment plugin for this
https://github.com/epheien/myjl